# Binary classification accuracy differance in TensorFlow and Torch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I am working on a binary classification problem. In my torch code below, I keep getting 2.5% accuracy.

```
class SimpleClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, output_size):
        super(SimpleClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size1, hidden_size2)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu1(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu2(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x

input_size = train_X.shape[1]
hidden_size1 = 64
hidden_size2 = 32
output_size = 1 
model = SimpleClassifier(input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, output_size)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)


num_epochs = 50
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for inputs, labels in train_dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        
        # Reshape labels to match the shape of the outputs
        labels = labels.view(-1, 1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    # Evaluation on the test set
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.eval()
        predictions = model(test_X).squeeze()
        predictions_binary = (predictions.round()).float()
        accuracy = torch.sum(predictions_binary == test_Y) / (len(test_Y) * 100)
        if(epoch%25 == 0):
          print("Epoch " + str(epoch) + " passed. Test accuracy is {:.2f}%".format(accuracy))
```

However, in my Tensorflow code which is below, I get accuracy around 86%

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=len(train_X[0]), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # assuming binary classification

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=50, batch_size=64)

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_Y)
print(f"Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}")
```

DataLoader for torch part:

```
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.056)

train_X = train[["A","B","C", "D"]].to_numpy()
test_X = test[["A","B", "C", "D"]].to_numpy()
train_Y = train[["label"]].to_numpy()
test_Y = test[["label"]].to_numpy()

train_X = torch.tensor(train_X, dtype=torch.float32)
test_X = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.float32)
train_Y = torch.tensor(train_Y, dtype=torch.float32)
test_Y = torch.tensor(test_Y, dtype=torch.float32)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_X, train_Y)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(test_X, test_Y)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

I believe somethings are really wrong in my torch code but I couldn't understand what I am missing? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the problem you can fix so:

```
accuracy = torch.sum(predictions == test_Y).item() / predictions.size(0) * 100
```

the wrong order for percent converting

Comment: In that way it is just returning "Epoch 0: Test accuracy is 25228.00%"

Comment: you should check what's your predictions shape and test_Y shape because it's strange you try to sum all the predictions more than 0,5 and then divide on whole dataset len and maximum it could achieve 100%

Comment: I understand you divide on batch size not for len of dataset, try change len(test_Y) to predictions.size(0)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm sharing a general workflow for binary classificaiton in keras and pytorch, following similar modeling structure you made. Run the following code, notice data type, shape, etc. It may help you to figure out the flaw in your code.

**creating dummy data**

```py
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
ytrain_binary = (ytrain % 2 == 0).astype('float32')
ytest_binary = (ytest % 2 == 0).astype('float32')
```

**keras codes**

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer((28, 28)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam', 
    loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(
    xtrain, ytrain_binary, 
    validation_data=(xtest, ytest_binary), 
    epochs=10, 
    batch_size=256
)

...
Epoch 9/10
1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0444 - accuracy: 0.9846 - val_loss: 0.1107 - val_accuracy: 0.9743
Epoch 10/10
1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0487 - accuracy: 0.9829 - val_loss: 0.1251 - val_accuracy: 0.9704
```

**pytorch codes**

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

class SimpleClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size1, hidden_size2)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size2, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.relu1(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu2(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x

batch_size = 256
input_size = 28 * 28
hidden_size1 = 64
hidden_size2 = 32
output_size = 1 

model = SimpleClassifier(
    input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, output_size
)
```

```py
train_dataset = TensorDataset(
    torch.from_numpy(xtrain), torch.from_numpy(ytrain_binary)
)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(
    torch.from_numpy(xtest), torch.from_numpy(ytest_binary)
)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True
)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(
    test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False
)
```

Assuming that, you have basic understanding about gradient and metrics calculations. Notice the data type, shape etc.

```py
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
num_epochs = 10

def torch_fit(model, train_dataloader):
    # on the train set
    model.train()
    total_train_loss = 0
    correct_train_predictions = 0
    total_train_samples = 0
    
    # loop over the data
    for inputs, labels in train_dataloader:
        # nn computation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs.float())
        labels = labels.view(-1, 1).float()  
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        # metric calculation
        total_train_loss += loss.item()
        predictions_binary = (outputs.round()).float()
        correct_train_predictions += torch.sum(predictions_binary == labels)
        total_train_samples += len(labels)
    
    train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)
    train_accuracy = correct_train_predictions / total_train_samples * 100
    return train_loss, train_accuracy


def torch_evaluate(model, test_dataloader):
    # on the test set
    model.eval()
    total_test_loss = 0
    correct_test_predictions = 0
    total_test_samples = 0
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        # loop over the data
        for test_inputs, test_labels in test_dataloader:
            # nn computation
            test_outputs = model(test_inputs.float())
            test_labels = test_labels.view(-1, 1).float()
            test_loss = criterion(test_outputs, test_labels)
            total_test_loss += test_loss.item()
            
            # metric calculation
            predictions_binary = (test_outputs.round()).float()
            correct_test_predictions += torch.sum(predictions_binary == test_labels)
            total_test_samples += len(test_labels)
            
    test_loss = total_test_loss / len(test_dataloader)
    test_accuracy = correct_test_predictions / total_test_samples * 100
    return test_loss, test_accuracy
    
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss, train_accuracy = torch_fit(model, train_dataloader)
    test_loss, test_accuracy = torch_evaluate(model, test_dataloader)
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}:")
    print(f"  Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Training Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.2f}%")
    print(f"  Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy:.2f}%\n")
```

```bash
Epoch 1:
  Training Loss: 0.1995, Training Accuracy: 93.00%
  Test Loss: 0.0846, Test Accuracy: 96.90%

Epoch 2:
  Training Loss: 0.0738, Training Accuracy: 97.44%
  Test Loss: 0.0665, Test Accuracy: 97.73%

Epoch 3:
  Training Loss: 0.0564, Training Accuracy: 98.05%
  Test Loss: 0.0657, Test Accuracy: 97.84%

Epoch 4:
  Training Loss: 0.0462, Training Accuracy: 98.43%
  Test Loss: 0.0541, Test Accuracy: 98.12%

Epoch 5:
  Training Loss: 0.0394, Training Accuracy: 98.65%
  Test Loss: 0.0558, Test Accuracy: 98.26%

Epoch 6:
  Training Loss: 0.0347, Training Accuracy: 98.85%
  Test Loss: 0.0620, Test Accuracy: 98.03%

Epoch 7:
  Training Loss: 0.0300, Training Accuracy: 98.97%
  Test Loss: 0.0594, Test Accuracy: 98.07%

Epoch 8:
  Training Loss: 0.0267, Training Accuracy: 99.07%
  Test Loss: 0.0653, Test Accuracy: 98.19%

Epoch 9:
  Training Loss: 0.0238, Training Accuracy: 99.13%
  Test Loss: 0.0646, Test Accuracy: 97.99%

Epoch 10:
  Training Loss: 0.0216, Training Accuracy: 99.24%
  Test Loss: 0.0626, Test Accuracy: 98.24%
```

or

```py
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred_torch = model(torch.from_numpy(xtest).float()).squeeze()
y_pred_binary = (y_pred_torch.round()).numpy()
correct_predictions = (ytest_binary == y_pred_binary).sum()
accuracy = correct_predictions / len(ytest) * 100
print("Test Accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy))
Test Accuracy: 98.24%
```

The above code is tested with tensorflow '2.13.0' and, torch '2.0.0+cpu' on kaggle env.